# How to selectively populate waterline associations via query param in sails.js

Tags: node.js, associations, sails.js, waterline

By default, sails will populate all relationships within a model when it's corresponding API route is hit. Does anyone know if it's possible to toggle this functionality? If I'm working with a one-to-many association, I may not want to populate the association when doing a listing of all items for performance reasons. But when viewing a single item, it would be nice to complete the population.

For example, say one ticket can have many comments. I don't care about the comments when fetching a case listing but would be important when viewing a specific case. I took a guess at how it could function but it fails:

```
localhost:1337/tickets?populate=false
```

### Update

I implemented the above functionality within [balderdashy/sails#1695](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/pull/1695). The only change is that you selectively choose which associations to populate using:

```
localhost:1337/tickets?populate=[]          // Don't populate anything
localhost:1337/tickets?populate=[comments]  // Only populate comments
```

This would override whatever is defined for `populate` within your blueprint config.

Comment: Pretty sure population is not turned on by default, you have to implicitly write it in query, like `User.findOne(user.id).populate('userFriends').exec(...)` (just a small example out of my head)

Comment: That is true if you are using Waterline directly. What I'm referring to is populations from a request URL which is processed by Sails blueprints. In that case, population is on by default unless you specify otherwise in `config/blueprints.js` with `populate = false`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about blueprints, sorry. Well, you can make your own route to lead to your controller.action and return results of query depending on url GET parameters.

Comment: I agree with @IļjaGubins. I dont think there is any way to do this using blueprint routes. You will have to override them if you want to do this

Comment: @jason Your solution works great. You should write the details as an answer. Btw, `?populate=false` works for me (using *sails-mysql* adapter)

Answer (score 10):

You just need to separate your assosiactions via `comma`, just like this:

```
localhost:1337/tickets?populate=comments,owner&SOME_OTHER_PARAMS
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. It works if I'm looking at a single record tho: `tickets/123?populate=comments`

Comment: this is wrong. it should be something like this `localhost:1337/tickets?populate=[comments,owner]&SOME_OTHER_PARAMS`

Comment: @philip maybe it's changed in  new version

Comment: what version were you guys using